# Eclipse crashes after few minutes (Debian, Oracle JDK 7, Kepler, 64bit, RAP)

Tags: linux, debian, 64-bit, java, eclipse

my eclipse keeps crashing on me after a few (3-5) minutes of use (that is: no crash if just open and I don't use it).

Mostly when I try to save (that works at first) or when calling the completion menu (CTRL-Space) on something.

I downloaded "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ today.

Java:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

The trouble was the same with OpenJDK which I used at first.

Linux:

```
Linux morbid 3.11-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.11.10-1 (2013-12-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
```

I would be supporting logs, but can't find them.

I tried increasing RAM (through entries in eclipse.ini), but that didn't make a difference either.